# restarting and presenting in GameScene

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, touchesbegan

Hello my problem is that when I click on a button to restart my game it will restart, but then if I click on a button that transitions to the MainMenuViewController than the scene will freeze.  The interesting thing is that if I restart the game and click on the segue button first it will work properly, but then if I click the restart button the game will then freeze.  When clicking on the segue button and it crashes I get the error has no segue with identifier 'GameToMain' when it indeed does work the first time.  When I click on the restart game it will just crash with no error.  Here is the relevant code for this problem:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let skView = view as! SKView
    let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
    //skView.showsPhysics = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)        
    scene.viewController = self
}
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var viewController: GameViewController!
```

This is set up in a func that is called when the player loses:

```
    let tryAgain = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    tryAgain.text = "Try Again?"
    tryAgain.color = SKColor.yellowColor()
    tryAgain.name = "retryLabel"
    tryAgain.fontSize = 28
    tryAgain.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    playerLayerNode.addChild(tryAgain)

    let mainMenuTransition = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    mainMenuTransition.text = "Main Menu"
    mainMenuTransition.color = SKColor.yellowColor()
    mainMenuTransition.name = "mainMenuTransitionSeque"
    mainMenuTransition.fontSize = 20
    mainMenuTransition.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2 - 60)
    playerLayerNode.addChild(mainMenuTransition)
```

This is how the labels register and react to being tapped

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches ) {
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
     let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            if (node.name == "retryLabel") {
                print("restart")
                let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                let transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
                gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
                gameScene.viewController = GameViewController()
                self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
                print("complete Reload")
            }

            if (node.name == "mainMenuTransitionSeque") {
                print("go to main menu")
                self.viewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameToMain", sender: self)
                print("complete2")

}
```

Comment: you should have the view controller that calls GameViewController dismiss it, also is the touches began inside the game scene code or the view controller?

Comment: It is in the Game Scene so right now it all behaves properly but the app will just crash when it is called again but the function will still be run and I can tell this since I set up a print() statement at the end of them and they both still run when either is tapped @Knight0fDragon

Comment: OK so if I am reading this correct,  you are creating a new scene inside a scene, thus the new scenes viewController variable is nil, and you are trying to dismiss from a nil

Comment: That was the problem. however my work around (though it has not worked completely for me yet) was to declare viewController again when the new scene is being created.  I will update my code to show this, however my app still crashes if the new scene is created and the segue is attempted. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: I would not be creating scenes inside scenes,  if I were you, I would be removing the scene from the view,  and then adding a new one,  is that the only reason view controller exists for a scene, to dismiss it? If that is the case,  I would look into creating a delegate. Apple prefers it if the parent view controller dismiss the child view controller

Comment: Another thing that may be happening, is when you dismiss the view controller,  you are not properly dismissing the scene.  I am not sure what code you have, but things like Timers and notifications need to be removed before the view controller can be removed,  and that could be causing the crashing

Comment: I will look into these methods but I did update my code to show you whats going on @Knight0fDragon

Comment: now you are adding view controller on top of view controller with the performSegue, this is bad lol

Comment: also  gameScene.viewController = GameViewController() is not what you want,  you want gameScene.viewController = self.viewController.  The former creates a new view controller,  the latter shares the viewController

Comment: haha well then this is why you are here :) so should I use self.viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) ...or... let MM = self.viewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainMenu") as! mainMenuViewController
                                                     self.viewController.presentViewController(MM, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: you need to understand how view controller works,  When you present a view controller like that ,  you are presenting  a new instance every time,  which means you keep adding onto the stack.  So if A presents B and then B presents A,  what you have is ABA in memory, not just A.  So if you are ever going back, you need to dismiss.  For now, put the dismiss in.  But make a note to rewrite it, because like I have been saying,  the parent should dismiss.  So A presents B,  B tells A that B is done.  A then dismisses B and goes back to being in charge.

Comment: I appreciate all that you are doing for me this has really been a big problem recently and you are helping a lot.  So you recommend just staying with the dismiss? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: yes you need to dismiss,  and I am guessing you need to add deinit{} to the game scene to stop anything that can keep it alive when the view removes it.  These are things like timers, blocks, notifications, gestures I believe, or anything else that can go off on its own thread or what not.  Infact, put a print("Game Scene Deinit") into the deinit so that we know it is being removed

Comment: perfect I will implement these all tomorrow when I have more time.  Thank you for steering me in the right direction I will let you know how it goes :) @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Ok so the dismiss works perfectly as planned :) and for my code I did not need to implement an deinit but I will keep that in mind in case I ever add anything.  The only problem left is that after I dismiss and the start the game up again when I hit the restart button the screen will freeze.  You have already helped me so much I did not know if you had any idea about this error? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: I have a feeling you may have a race condition because you are in a scene,  removing the scene from the parent, and adding a new scene to parent,  did you move the restart functionality outside of the scene yet?

Comment: I can see how it would be a race condition since I am getting no errors or threads.  How should I move the restart functionality outside of the scene when its job is to restart the scene? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: you are not restarting a scene,  you are literally destroying the old scene and placing in a new one,  instead what you want to to is on restart, notify the view some how  (Look into NSNotifcationCenter),  then the view will have a restart function that will remove the old scene and create the new scene

Comment: ok I will look into that solution thank you @Knight0fDragon

Comment: should I still attempt to use NSNotificationCenter if my button to restart the game is generated programmatically in GameScene? Most of the examples I am noticing use NSNotificationCenter to communicate storyboard buttons between the GameViewController and GameScene @Knight0fDragon

Comment: you can use it for anything,  the point of it is to send data and info from 1 object to another without the need for global variables. Plus, it can be read  by multiple objects which makes it nice.  I would start with the NSNotificationCenter just to get it working outside of the scene,  then switch to the delegate method like you would with view controllers when you are ready to optimize

Comment: So what you are recommending is to create another scene for when the game is over and restart the game there? Because currently I just have a label appear when the player loses that is clicked to restart the scene.  That is why I am unsure if NSNotificationCenter and the delegate would be useful since I am still doing everything in the same scene when restarting and am not using multiple objects. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: you do not understand your code then:  let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)  This is creating a new object,  this is not resetting anything, this creates a new scene every time, so no matter where you do this, you are making a new scene

Comment: here, join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92604/restarting-and-presenting-in-gamescene so that we don't get in trouble for extending comments beyond the question

Comment: Perfect so all I need to do is destroy the old scene before the new scene is created. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: you want create the new scene before you destroy the old scene to avoid the loading time, just don't present it in the view till you are outside of the old scene (which is when you are inside the view object,) So in summary,  the old scene tells the view it is done, the view creates the new scene, adds the new scene to the view, the old scene should have no more references to it, and destroys itself

Comment: I understand how one would create a new scene based off my current code but how would you destroy the old scene.  I have found no func or online help for this. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: That is what is wonderful about ARC,  as long as you have no reference to it, it will release.  Now keep in mind  there may be a reference holding onto it beyond what you may think,  things like blocks and timers add to the reference count

Comment: If it is a CFTimeInterval does it need to be released? If so how would this be done @Knight0fDragon

Comment: It is a data type, like int,  it is not a process that runs on a queue, so no it does not need to be released by you, Apple will do it.  From Apple:Core Foundation measures time in units of seconds. The base data type is the CFTimeInterval, which measures the difference in seconds between two times.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/

Comment: Since I have no timers in my application I am guessing it has to do with the closures except i have researched it and it appears to me in swift that the ARC releases them already.  @Knight0fDragon

Comment: It will release them as long as they are not holding onto a reference to anything that would cause a strong reference cycle, especially to the object that created it(I.E. block contains reference to self, self contains reference to block,)  are you sure your old scene is still alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the current code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let skView = view as! SKView
    let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    //skView.showsFPS = true
    //skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
    //skView.showsPhysics = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene.viewController = self
    skView.presentScene(scene)        

}

}
```

In GameScene

```
var viewController: GameViewController!
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            if (node.name == "retryLabel") {

                let skView = view as SKView!
                let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
                scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                scene.viewController = viewController.self
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }

            if (node.name == "mainMenuTransitionSeque") {
                self.viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                print("complete2")
            }

        }

    }
}
```

So basically to restart the scene I copy and pasted the code from the GameViewController into GameScene so that it would restart the scene exactly, but the key was redeclaring the viewController variable.  Then to get to the mainMenu I dismissed the view controller (GameScene) instead of creating a new segue so that I do not keep adding more and more scenes on top of each other.